# %N backreference inside RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain, backreference

I'm working on a virtual domain system. I have a wildcard DNS set up as `*.loc`, and I'm trying to work on my `.htaccess` file. The following code works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.loc$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example/
RewriteRule (.*) /example/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But, I want this to work with anything I put in. However, I need the `%{REQUEST_URI}` checked against the text found as the domain. I tried using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9-]*.)?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.loc$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%3/
RewriteRule (.*) /%3/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%3/` causes my code to throw an Internal Server Error. I understand this is because of the %N in my code but is there a way I can work with it? I need this line, otherwise, my code fails from internal redirects.

I hope this makes sense to someone. All I need is to be able to backreference a RewriteCond in a following RewriteCond.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There's 2 things that you are doing wrong here.

First, your `%{HTTP_HOST}` regex is no good. You need to escape the `.` dots otherwise they'll be treated as "any character that's not a newline". This essentially makes the `%3` backreference the last character of the hostname before the TLD (e.g. `http://blah.bar.loc`, **%3** = `r`).

Second, you can't use backreferences in the regex of a `RewriteCond`, only the left side string, it's sort of a weird limitation. However, you can use the `\1` references, in the regex so that you can construct a clever left side string to match against. Something like `%3::%{REQUEST_URI}` and then you can match like this: `!^(.*?)::/\1/?`. This regex essentially says: "match and group the first block of text *before* the **::**, then make sure the block of text following the **::** starts with `/(first block)`".

So your rules should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.loc$ [NC]
RewriteCond %3::%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*?)::/\1/?
RewriteRule (.*) /%3/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Cheers! I have no idea what the hell that line really does, but it works. For now, I'm happy with that. Your help is hugely appreciated :)

Comment: Where on earth is this documented. This answer deserves so many more up-votes. I vote we unaccept the answer, put bounty on, and reaccept.

Comment: Is there a link to any documentation? What :: are for?

Comment: @EdikMkoyan the "::" is just a way to match against the `%3::%{REQUEST_URI}`. You can use whatever you want but it just needs to be unlikely to show up as part of the URI