# .htaccess Rewrite URL to directory that is the same as domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a list of domains that all point to the same IP Address and I want to be able to dynamically rewrite the url to go to a folder based on the domain name.

For example, I want `coolsite.com/blah.php` to point to `/coolsite/blah.php`.

I have the following in my .htaccess file, but it doesn't work

```
#Capture the domain without the 'www' or '.com'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)\.com

#if the request hasn't been rewritten to the new folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1

#Rewrite request so that it inserts that folder in the path
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

I know I can just make a bunch of `VirtualHost`s in my httpd.conf, but there are a ton of domains that I'm using.

Is it even possible to do this with mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `%1` on RHS of `RewriteCond`.

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}::%{REQUEST_URI} ^(?:www\.)?(.+?)\.com::(?!\1).+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15981056/2498122).

As anubhava said, you can't use a backreference in the RHS of `RewriteCond` but you *can* use it in the LHS.

My final code is:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} (?:www\.)?(.+?)\..+$
RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*?)::/\1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```