# Folder and php file with the same name in website

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How do i make it so this:

```
www.example.com/product
```

Will point to this file: `/product.php` but this:

```
www.example.com/product/thing.php
```

Will point to this directory: `/product/thing.php`

I have these rewrite rules in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It's making this:

```
www.example.com/product.php
```

Into this:

```
www.example.com/product
```

Comment: What is the problem? What URL are you trying to use and what error are you getting?

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33319570/5397119

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toggle the [`DirectorySlash`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) to **Off**.

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out you can do something else that is almost as good.

```
www.example.com/product
```

becomes:

```
www.example.com/product/
```

If you add a 'index.php' or 'index.html' in the product directory on the web server. So the path becomes product/index.php, and the url will look like this:

```
www.example.com/product/
```