# How to use .htaccess file to get the subdomain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect https://aaa.subdomain.example.com/path to https://subdomain.example.com/aaa/path 
But how to do that with apache .htaccess file?
I tried this, however, it didn't work :(

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://subdomain.example.com/%1/${REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important: the following instructions are for information purposes only. You may need to change the code so that it works in your situation.

Using your FTP software or our FTP Manager, add and adapt the following code in the .htaccess file located in the root of your Website:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/ -d
RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*?)::/1/?
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1" [L]
```

Explanations for the third line: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/15981056][1]

In the first line replace:

domain with your domain name
com with your domain name extension (ch, fr, etc.)

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work either. The browser just kept returning a 404 error, it seemed that it didn't rewrite the URL at all.

Comment: @Dounick did you enable mod_rewrite?

Comment: Ah! That's a really silly mistake!!! But here comes a new problem, it always returns a 403 code, and I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: Oh, it's OK now, I solved it by changing %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} to the domain that I want to redirect to, thank you!