# Submitted form redirect to input URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to make an HTML form with a Text box labeled "enter your store ID" and a `submit` button.

Then when the `submit` button is hit I want them re-directed to a different website with the subdomain being what entered.

Examples:
if "12345" is entered, they get redirected to `12345.myothersite.com`
if "987654" is entered, they get redirected to `987654.myothersite.com`

Comment: Try this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167068/apache-mod-rewrite-a-subdomain-to-a-subfolder-via-internal-redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've tagged this jQuery I presume you are okay with a jQuery answer.

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
  <input id="subdomain"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = "http://" + $("#subdomain").val() + ".somesite.com/"
  });
});
```

Comment: `window.location = ...` won't work in some browsers, `window.location.href = ...` is compatible with most browsers

Comment: I've not seen it in any modern browser, but you are right that it could break some old browsers. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = document.getElementById('inputBox').value + '.myothersite.com';
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/53q2jf2k/

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
    <input type="text" id="inputBox"/>
    <button  onclick="changeURL()" >Submit</button>
</form>


function changeURL() {
    window.location.href = document.getElementById('inputBox').value + '.myothersite.com';

  alert(document.getElementById('inputBox').value + '.myothersite.com')
}
```